# How does Wordpress make the system able to update itself?

Tags: php, wordpress, updates

I have a website I want to be able to do the same kind of core update that [WordPress](http://wordpress.org/) can do.

*How do I safely make it possible to update the core of my website? **Which preventive measures do I take?***

When PHP scripts are able to update themselves it sounds like a great security threat to me!

Comment: What exactly are your concerns? What does "insecure" mean in your question? Receiving the zipped update from a trusted source? unzipping it and replacing files without the site going through "partially unzipped" states where some files are already overwritten, some are not? making sure the unzipping only occurs if triggered by an authenticated admin? making sure the unzipping occurs only if wordpress has write access to all necessary files?

Comment: I don't see how it's possible to answer this without writing a book...

Comment: @MihaiStancu : good considerations. You could almost have received an accepted answer for that!

Comment: Can't receive an accepted answer for a comment. And since my comment doesn't contain an answer only further questions it's not an appropriate answer for SO, it's just some "qualified guidance". Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want, you can look at the source of [`/wordpress/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php`](http://core.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-upgrader.php) which is doing all the heavy lifting in the new background updates. Major releases (3.7 to 3.8, or 3.x to 4.x) require user input. It's just small patches that are coming in automatically.

1. Your WordPress installation pings the WP servers for available updates.
2. Your WP downloads archive from their server to yours, and unpacks the archive to a working directory.
3. Your WP deletes the package archive.
4. Your WP moves the new files from the working directory to their destination.
5. Your WP clears the working directory.
6. Your WP calls filters and hooks 'upgrader_process_complete' which may initiate some new code to execute in order to complete the patches.

Unless a hacker is able to trick WordPress into connecting to a non-WP server for update information or packages, you're getting approved file patches direct from WordPress servers `api.wordpress.org`.

Comment: That's what I needed to know. See, it wasn't so difficult :) Then I just need to figure out how to determine whether I can write to the filesystem or if I will have to use FTP to replace the files.

Comment: Together with Mihai's comment to question above this is a good answer.

Comment: @Set Sail Media could you please explain a litle bit more how does the overwrite happen ?

Comment: The actual install exists in function `install_package()` in class `WP_Upgrader`. This class uses another WordPress class `WP_Filesystem`. Each updated directory is individually moved to its permanent location from the working directory. In some cases, WP deletes the original item first. In other cases, it simply moves the new file.